# Error on adding iOS platform to phonegap project

Tags: ios, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

I have got next error when I try to add iOS platform after delete it from phonegap project:

```
> /usr/local/bin/phonegap platform add ios
Adding ios project...

    Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:

    Path: platforms/ios

Package: com.domain.app
Name: app

iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.3.1

Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "com.adobe.plugins.GAPlugin". Please try adding it again.

    Process finished with exit code 1 at 14:12:14.
Execution time: 6,684 ms.
```

Plugin `com.adobe.plugins.GAPlugin` is deleted 4 month ago and there are no usage of them in the project.

Does anyone have idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: is this plugin mentioned in config.xml ?
if yes, then please remove it from the plugin list.

Comment: No, this plugin not mentioned in `config.xml` file. And that is strange

Comment: may be that plugin's folder exist in plugin folder. So remove from it.

Comment: @Hiten your mean `phonegap/plugins` under `plugin's folder`?

Comment: yes, remove from that folder.

Comment: @Hiten ok I'll check it when I get access to project. Thanks for help. If it was missing here I'll write to figure out what caused that problem

Comment: @Hiten yes there was `com.adobe.plugins.GAPlugin` in plugin folder. Post it as answer and I accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the `com.adobe.plugins.GAPlugin` plugin folder from the main plugin folder.